# Biased coin flip from an unbiased coin flip

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

Von Neumman's method allows us to generate a fair coin flip from any unbiased coin flip using only two bits (two tosses) of information (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin).

Is the reverse possible? Generating any arbritrary Bernoulli random variable with a fair one ($p = \frac {1} {2}$) with two bits of information. I know we can approximate a uniform distribution with infinite fair Bernoulli tosses. I'm not so sure if this can be done using two bits of information.

Comment: Can you clarify - are you looking for a result with two bits of information? Or with finitely many?

Comment: I'm unclear about either of them. But I am interested  in the result with only two bits of information. I've altered the question to reflect this.

Comment: Given that there are numbers that cannot be encoded in two bits of information, it seems extremely unlikely that this is possible.

Comment: My intuition is similar. Do you think its possible with a finite number of bits?

Comment: If $p$ has a finite expansion in base $2$, then yes. If $p$ is irrational, then for a similar reason to the two bits case, I think not.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using only two bits of information"? Note that von Neumann's procedure may require more than two tosses (in fact there is no upper bound on the number of tosses it may require).

Comment: Indeed, you are right there is no upper bound to the number of tosses. By two bits however, I meant that at any point we only need to remember the outcome of two tosses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that with two flips of a fair coin (two bits of information) you can only simulate the probabilities $\frac14, \frac12, \frac34$ (and, trivially $0$ and $1$).

This is because you have an equiprobable sample space of $4$ outcomes, so all events have probability $\frac{k}4$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted this as the answer because I feel it addresses the question as stated. Mick A's answer is also an interesting thing to think about. For anyone whose curious, this can be done with an expected number of bits being 2.

Answer (score 5):

I think it can be done using a method similar to von Neumann's.

Suppose you want to produce a Bernoulli trial - a simulated coin toss - with probability of heads being $p = \dfrac{a}{b}$, with $a \leq b$, both non-negative integers, $b \neq 0$ (so that $0 \leq p \leq 1$).

Begin a series of toss sequences with a fair coin, each sequence being $b$ tosses in length.

At the completion of each sequence, if it has not had exactly $a$ heads, discard that sequence and begin a new sequence. However, if it has had exactly $a$ heads, then the process stops and we take the result of the first toss in that sequence. The probability of the result being a head should be $\dfrac{a}{b}$, as required.

This makes it achievable for rational $p$. I suspect transcendental $p$ (e.g. $\frac{1}{\pi}$) would be impossible to generate but that algebraic irrationals (e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$) might be possible.